# botbuilder-ai sdk's datetimereference in LuisRecognizerOptionsV3 not working

Tags: botframework

The "datetimereference" option is not using the current timestamp.

I tried ISO format and (2020-01-01 00:00:00) format.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this or are you still seeking help?